# How many bits would it take to name roughly 8000 species of animals?

Tags: binary, binary-data, bit

How many bits would it take to name 800,000 species of insects? I was wondering if you could even come up with a specific number. Wouldn't the number of bits differ for every name based on it's length? In such case how can you know how many bits would be needed to name 800,000 species of insects?

(I'm reading about Computer Architecture and Design, and I found this brain teaser)

Comment: Sounds more like an interview question than something you read in a book. Interviewers use this sort of question to evaluate your thinking skills, not because there's an actual answer. Doesn't sound like you did well. :-)

Comment: No this was not for any interview. It's just a kind of a brain teaser relating to Computer Architecture and Design. Plus I just started learning about the things under the hood of a Computer.

Answer (score 1):

You could approximate this if you knew the average length of each insect name (in characters) and multiplied it by 8 (the number of bits in an ascii character representation).

For example (assuming the average number of letters per insect name is 10):

```
800000 * 8 * 10 = 64000000
<numberOfInsects> * <numberOfBitsPerCharacter> * <averageNumberOfLettersPerName> = <totalNumberOfBitsNeeded>
```

You wouldn't need to use ascii to represent all of the names, however. Since there are only 26 letters in the alphabet, you really would only need to use 5 bits (2^5 = 32) to store each letter. Then you'd have:

```
800000 * 5 * 10 = 40000000
```

This would be 24000000 less bits (for this example).

Answer (score 1):

If  numbers are allowed in the name of species, you could just name them `species #123456`. Storing each of these names needs 20 bits, since only the number is relevant information, while the text `species #` is redundant.

If the names cannot contain numbers but can be generated from a running number without further knowledge, i.e. a function `generateName(n)`, you also need only 20 bits.

When you have a list of predefined names, each at most `len` characters long and consisting of the alphabet `a-z` and a space, you need `800000 * (log(len) / log(2) + len * log(26 + 1) / log(2))` bits per name.

Since the question is vague, it is difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depend from each name length and what do you want to use for save the data (database, txt, json, csv, etc.).

but if we want to calcolate assuming with the name length to 20 char always using spaces for short names and comma to separate the number is:

```
 (800000 x 20) + (800000) = 16800000 bytes 16.02173 Mb
```